# How to iterate throught Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, loops, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to iterate my data from Firebase Realtime Database

[image: Database]

but my code always returning null

Any help will be appreciated, also if  there is a way to store the data in an Arraylist according to the user name it will be great.

thanks

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("INFO").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String Age = ds.child("Age").getValue(String.class);
            String Job = ds.child("Job").getValue(String.class);
           Log.d("TAG", Age + " " + Job);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, please add your code as text here. It's much easier to see/handle that way.

Comment: @tvicky4j247 Hi, thanks for the hint, added as code now

Comment: You should be using `getValue(User.class)` where that's an object with your two fields

Comment: @mSeventeen Is something printed out when using `Log.d("TAG", Age + " " + Job);`? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, null null is printed out

Comment: @mSeventeen Are you sure the picture is genuine? You have two colons. Beside that, show us the exact logcat with null.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any extra ":" with field name than remove it, after that you can access data either using model class with Age and Job field or using HashMap.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("INFO").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          HashMap<String,String> map= (HashMap<String, String>) ds.getValue();

          String Age = map.get("Age");
          String Job =  map.get("Job");
          Log.d("TAG", Age + " " + Job);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: If the `:` is indeed in the key itself, you can also get its value with `String Age = map.get("Age:");` or `String Age = snapshot.child("Age:").getValue(String.class);`.